# when static or dynamic initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

Is initialization using default constructor (compiler generated) 
"static initialization" or "dynamic initialization"?

I mean that in

```
class test{
  int m;

public :
  test(): m(12) {}

};

test i;

int main()
{//
}
```

Here when is `i` getting initialized - at compile time or is it dynamic initialization i.e. is it safe to use `i` in other files for initialisation or other things?
What if user has defined default constructor?

Comment: The crux of the question is this: "How does initialisation of global/namespace scope objects happen when those objects have a user-defined constructor?". The answer can be found in `§3.6.2` of the standard. In this case `i.m` will be statically initialized to zero, and dynamically initialized to 12, however, if the default constructor were declared `constexpr`, then `i.m` would be statically initialized to 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `test` has a constructor, it will be run when the object is initialized. The object will be place into a memory area which is initialized to zero. You can even test this by initializing values using `i.m` before and after the object is created:

```
extern test i;
int dummy1 = i.m;
test i;
int dummy2 = i.m;
```

When you then print `dummy1` and `dummy2` you should get `0` and `12`, respectively. If you want to statically initialize `i` you would need to use something like

```
test i = { 12 };
```

This only works with PODs, however. All that said, note that global data is always bad. Just don't bother and do things properly.